# Тестирование программного обеспечения

Tags: тестирование

1. Кто работал тестировщиком программного обеспечения? Что представляет из себя эта профессия?
2. Расскажите каким инструментарием вы пользовались для выявления "дыр" и багов в программах или сайтах?
3. В какие сроки можно реально протестировать программу или сайт, достаточно сложный по функционалу и структуре?
4. Можно ли обычному программисту быстро въехать в эту работу (потому что программист тоже в каком-то смысле тестировщик, когда отлаживает свой продукт)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Профессия представляет из себя прохождение по тем же маршрутам, по которым ходит пользователь. Как правило, шишки за ошибки ПОСЛЕ тестировщика сыплются именно на него: не проверил.
2. Есть множество автоматических заполнителей форм и скриптовых примочек для браузера, типа селениума. Но самое качественное - руками, зная исходники.
3. Время разработки*0.5. Это в среднем.
4. Можно. Но тяжело. Проще воспитать либо из оооочень крутого программера (уже знает, где и что обычно отваливается, ибо есть опыт), либо из программера-неудачника (постоянно натыкается на глюки), либо из простого юзера (мышление совершенно иное).

P.S. Простейшие моменты, которые обязан проверить еще программер: фильтрация инпутов, прямой доступ к закрытым разделам.